# Access and change 2d Json Array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access and change the data I receive from a JSON api call.

The format of the call is like this:

```
{
  "count": 391,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "name": "name1",
      "url": "url1",
      "project": {
        "id": "projId",
        "name": "BT-GIT",
        "url": "otherurl",
        "state": "wellFormed"
      },
      "defaultBranch": "master",
      "remoteUrl": "remote"
    },
     {
      "id": "id2",
      "name": "name2",
      "url": "url2",
      "project": {
        "id": "projId",
        "name": "BT-GIT",
        "url": "otherurl",
        "state": "wellFormed"
      },
      "defaultBranch": "master",
      "remoteUrl": "remote"
    },...
```

and I want to add an extra entry to each "value", such that I have:

```
       {
          "id": "id1",
          "name": "name1",
          "url": "url1",
          "project": {
            "id": "projId",
            "name": "BT-GIT",
            "url": "otherurl",
            "state": "wellFormed"
          },
          "defaultBranch": "master",
          "remoteUrl": "remote"
          "date": "date" <---------
        }
```

I've tried:

```
$.each(data, function (idx) {
              data.value[idx].currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 16);
          })
```

and:

```
$.each(data, function (idx) {
              data[1][idx].currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 16);
          })
```

any Ideas on how I could remedy this problem?

Much thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're iterating on `data`, when it sounds like ou want to iterate on `data.value`. `$.each(data.value, function...` might do the trick.

Comment: The documentation explains how to iterate overan object using `$.each` pretty clearly: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with your existing code but just need slightly tweaking,

```
var data = {
    "count": 391,
    "value": [{
        "id": "id1",
        "name": "name1",
        "url": "url1",
        "project": {
            "id": "projId",
            "name": "BT-GIT",
            "url": "otherurl",
            "state": "wellFormed"
        },
        "defaultBranch": "master",
        "remoteUrl": "remote"
    }, {
        "id": "id2",
        "name": "name2",
        "url": "url2",
        "project": {
            "id": "projId",
            "name": "BT-GIT",
            "url": "otherurl",
            "state": "wellFormed"
        },
        "defaultBranch": "master",
        "remoteUrl": "remote"
    }]
};

$.each(data.value, function (index,data) {
              data.currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 16);
          });
console.log(data);
```

See Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/mj3vu6s6/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
data.value = data.value.map(function(v) { v.date = Date.now() })
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map